# What is interpolation between $L^2(\Omega)$ and $\mathring{H^2}(\Omega)$ when $\Omega$ is not smooth

Tags: interpolation-spaces

Let $\mathring{H}^\theta$ be the closure of $\mathcal{D}(\Omega)$ under the norm $\mathring{H}^\theta$.
It is well-known that 
$$
[L^2(\Omega), \mathring{H^{2}}(\Omega)]_{\theta}=\mathring{H^{2\theta}}(\Omega) \quad \forall \theta\in[0,1]\, \text{and } \theta\neq \frac{3}{4} 
$$
when $\Omega$ is bounded and smooth. What is the interpolation result when $\Omega$ is Lipschitz continuous. What is the optimal regularity for $\partial\Omega$ to make such interpolation result hold.

It seems that if $\Omega$ is $C^{1,1}$, then this is true.

Comment: @WillieWong Sorry. Actually, $\theta=s$